# Are there any ASP.NET MVC Real Time View Editors?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, editor

I'm looking for a tool and I'm not even sure of the proper name.  Please be patient with me as I explain.

I'm doing a lot of HTML/MVC 2 work.  Using the standard MVC 2 view engine, I would like to have an editor that shows real time changes in the browser.  If I re-arrange div elements containing standard HTML and some server side components, I would like the browser to update without a manual refresh.

Are there any tools that are currently available that would meet that requirement?

Comment: I'm a big fan of Less.js, that has a Live watch mode (it only refreshes the css but is still a valuable tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use firefox, you can use [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115) plugin and set up refresh every x seconds. This will simulate real time editing.

Comment: +1 I think @BenMaddox means (something) like in VS where you can have Design|Split|Source views and it's be great if VS did Design and Split views. If not then yeah ReloadEvery is the tool. Then again, does something like this exist for WebForms?

Comment: I considered this option. It wasn't exactly what I had in mind, but it  might be close enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's an automatic refresh-on-change tool for IE.  It's called ReloadIt, and is available at http://reloadit.codeplex.com . Free.  It works with ASPNET MVC, or any server side technology. It does not require IIS.  It does require IE.

It's not an add-on to IE, just a companion tool.  It does not change the IE install, does not install a BHO or anything like that.  So very low-impact installation.

You choose a URL that you'd like to auto-reload, and specify one or more directory paths to monitor for changes.  Press F12 to start monitoring.

[image]

After you set it, minimize it.  Then edit your content files, in whatever tool you prefer to use. When you save, the page gets reloaded.  like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @LukLed suggested, [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/) is a plug in that will refresh your browser screen automatically.

Instead of refreshing every X seconds, XRefresh will watch a directory tree/set of files and only refresh when one of them changes.

It's great in multi-monitor setups, and saves a few seconds when switching between windows in single monitor setups.